# REST Call from setup() function - ionic - vue.js

Tags: rest, vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-component, ionic4

I am currently struggling to make a REST Call to an external API from the setup function of my Ionic Vue Application.
I tried it in the following way:

```
const oResponse = fetch(
   "url"
     ).then((Response) => Response.json());

return { Items: [{ name: 'Milch', Flag: '*' }, { name: 'Wasser', Flag: '*' },{name: 'BraTee', Flag: '*'}], currentRec: oResponse.recipes }
```

The Return structure looks like this:

```
{
  recipes": [
    { ... },
    { ... }
 ]
}
```

I can not get it to work because Ionic says "oResponse does not have a component called 'recipes'.

How would I deal with this error and fetch a REST call properly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of `oResponse.recipes`, try `oResponse.data.recipes`.

Comment: @Ani Thanks for the answer! But this also does not work ...

Comment: Maybe you should re write your api request. Please check out my answer, since there is no enough space here in the comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should re write the api request. I usually use `axios` library to make api calls. Something like:

```
axios
      .post("url")  // Methods you can use also: .get , .put
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
       console.log(
          "an error occurred"
        );
      });
```

`npm install axios` --> to install axios library

`import axios from "axios";` ---> to import it in the component